# JS increase two counter where the 2nd as a relationship with the second

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm trying to increment a counter by a specific % only when a certain condition is met. I don't have access to the other counter function but only the output which is numbers. Specifically.

I have a function countdown which its output is a number changing from 100 to 1.

I have a let size = 0.

When the countdown hit 10 (10 inclusive) let size get added by 5%.

```
 10 = +5%
    9 = +10%
    8 = + 15%
```

etc.. until 1 = 50%

I'm trying to work with modulos and changing the base to work on `(/0,05*100)` but I could'nt get any result.

Also, for searching related resources what should I type into google? Is my title correct?

Thank you in advance

adding more accurate information

Comment: Maybe post the code you already have so it might be clearer as to what you're asking?

Comment: I don't have a code yet, I have only a function which perform a countdown and its output is a number.

Comment: I added more informations

Answer (score 0):

You could take the difference of ten and multiply by five and add an offset of five.

```js
var i = 10;

do {
    console.log(i, (10 - i) * 5 + 5);
} while (--i)
```